# Retrieve all products with same metadata value in Stripe

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

In Stripe (using Next.js and Node.js), I'm trying to retrieve all products with the same key-value pair in their metadata:

example: retrieve all products with
`metadata: {category: 'foo'}`

In attempts to render category-specific pages, I don't want to list and parse through my whole catalog but I also know that products can only be retrieved through `id` ([docs](https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/retrieve)), inferring that I would have to:

```
list all products 
for all products:
  if metadata matches, 
    add id to array
for id array:
  retrieve each
```

This is brute forcing though, and not a good idea.

What would be the best way to retrieve conditionally based on `metadata`?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stripe’s API currently doesn’t support querying Products using metadata. You’d have to retrieve all Products and filter through them. Stripe does have a Search API [2] which is currently in Beta so you might want to write in to see if you qualify.

If you happen to keep a track of Products server-side in a database, you could add an additional column for category. You can query your database by category to find those specific Products and then include just those Product IDs using the `ids` [2] parameter when you retrieve them through Stripe.

[1] https://stripe.com/docs/search-api

[2] https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/list#list_products-ids

Comment: This is a good idea. For now, I've created a local path integration using a modification of the tutorial [found here](https://flaviocopes.com/nextjs-cache-data-globally/).

Answer (score 2):

Stripe's Search API has been released and is no longer in beta. You can retrieve products using metadata per your original request. Example from Stripe documentation:

```
const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_i3ykuKQXMT0WrWVLRUmPODl2');

const product = await stripe.products.search({
  query: 'metadata[\'category\']:\'foo\'',
});
```

Full documentation here:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/products/search